# Windows 10 Pro master volume control for USB DAC

Tags: windows, usb, audio

I have upgraded my computer sound system to a external USB DAC (NAD 3020: http://nadelectronics.com/products/digital-music/D-3020-Hybrid-Digital-Amplifier ). While I was using my old system, that was connected to the lineout 3.5 plug, I could always use my keyboard media keys to change the Windows master volume and thereby changing the speaker volume. This is no longer the case since I switched to the USB DAC. The Windows master volume control does not effect the sound anymore, unless I turn it down to zero - which turns off the sound.
Now it seem like only the playing application can change the volume. For example can I play an mp3 using VLC and there change the volume.

Is there a way to get the functionality where I can change the volume using Windows master volume control?